# iReport table with additional record repeating for each row

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I searched all over the Internet and also on this forum but i can't find a way to achieve something like the table below. I'm using *iReport* 4.7.1.

Please could give me a hint?

[image]

Comment: As I understand right the ***Details about row #*** it is an `additional record` in your terminology. Am I right? Can you post your *jrxml* file?

Comment: Yes, the **Details about row #** is an additional record which I want to span on all the columns exactly like in the picture above. I can't give you an jrxml file because there isn't any. All my previous tries have failed so i don't have anything to show except what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is quite easy. You should add the *textField* element to the *Detail* band below the *textFields* with fields.

Here is a sample.

The report design in *iReport*:

[image: The report's design in iReport]

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ..>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, street, city FROM ADDRESS]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="STREET" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[City]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Street]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{STREET}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="300" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Details about row " + $V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be:

[image: The result in iReport via preview]

Comment: Thank you very much Alex but it is possible to achieve the same output using a table component?

Comment: @AndreiT As I know, No. The *Table* component does not allow to merge several cells in such manner. Actually, the *Table* component has mechanism for grouping columns, but I don't think that it can help you to solve this issue

Comment: @AndreiT You can also read [Table Component: Merge cell](http://jasperforge.org/questions/533770/resolved-table-component-merge-cell) post and [Is thare a easy way to merge cells](http://jasperforge.org/questions/510952/thare-easy-way-merge-cells) on http://jasperforge.org

Comment: Before posting here I already tried to group the columns but this grouping is available only on the column header and footer of the table therefore that grouped record can not be repeated for every record from the table. 
The only solution is the one provided by you and I thank you again for your trouble.

Comment: @AndreiT Yes, I think the grouping for details cells (in *Table* component) will be helpful