# Table with additional record repeating for each row with condition if and only if additional detail does not null

Tags: jasper-reports

My problem is much similar like as [iReport table with additional record repeating for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579390/ireport-table-with-additional-record-repeating-for-each-row) 
But there should be condition in printing that if and only if additional detail does not null.

If additional detail were null then start printing the next row in the place of otherdetails.
In below photo **row0** have no any details so "Detail about row0" is not print and next row "**row1**" take place.[image]

*.jrxml it is same code as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579390/ireport-table-with-additional-record-repeating-for-each-row)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0cd60d2c-0de5-44c1-8e55-88a8506b1b19">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from tbl_contact_details order by address_id asc]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ADDRESS_ID" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="LINE1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="LINE2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>    
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="ca4c166d-4e80-4aee-998f-9bf72fc09d82"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="131" height="20" uuid="92c185c2-b983-4328-94f6-75f5cce6e1a4"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[City]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="331" y="0" width="224" height="20" uuid="dbc15243-3212-4911-ab6d-8e5a5f75a38e"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Locality]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="41" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="41" uuid="5cb2a2e0-1e93-4feb-9760-bd1cb7bec02f"/>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="331" y="0" width="224" height="20" uuid="23183b68-362d-494e-acf0-93ff7fc31d19"/>
                    <box leftPadding="10">
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LINE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="75ba684c-c6bc-4129-bb3c-e045317f7084"/>
                    <box leftPadding="10">
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ADDRESS_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="131" height="20" uuid="93f12b46-e069-4435-8073-1bf122b06393"/>
                    <box leftPadding="10">
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="555" height="21" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="7c215a29-76be-4462-bef6-71f1d81e337f"/>
                    <box leftPadding="10">
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LINE2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="53" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Right now I am getting this result
[image]
but i want like this
[image]

Comment: Can you post the sample (*jrxml*) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi Alex K you had gave this code as an answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579390/ireport-table-with-additional-record-repeating-for-each-row

Comment: You can put that "Details about row" field in a detail band by itself which is displayed only conditionally, i.e. if there is something to show.

Comment: I have to apply a condition if($F{detail} != null) but it reserved the blank space.
But i want to fill that place with next row and so on

Comment: Alex I have updated the question please check.

Answer (score 1):

just try

```
$F{detail}!=null && $F{detail}.trim().length()>0
```

in the Print When Expression